# Can this be proved using single variable calculus or there's something wrong with this problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, recreational-mathematics

If $y^{1/m} + y^{-1/m} = 2x$ then prove that $(x^2 - 1)y_{n+2} + (2n + 1)x y_{n+1} + (n^2 - m^2)y_n = 0$?

Where $y_n$ denotes the $n^th$ derivative of $y$. This is a question of successive differentiation and has to be proved using Principle of mathematical induction. But I seem to make no considerable progress while attempting to solve this using successive differentiation.

The question I wrote I same as mentioned in my textbook. I'm wondering without mentioning anything about the variables n, m how can it be solved. Is there any approach. Is there anything that one can assume to proceed further.

This is a problem from single variable calculus text. I'm a beginner to single variable calculus. 
I have tried it using successive differentiation rule of leibnitz but unable to reach my answer.

Comment: What are the $y_{n}$ terms?

Comment: @T.Eskin I think it looks fine now.

Comment: The variables in that question are unclear - what is $x, y$ and  what are $y_n$?  Are $m, n $ integers? Where did you get this question?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Macavity yeah but there's nothing mentioned in the text apart from what I wrote here. I'm also confused.

Comment: @Macavity the question is from a genuine text I don't think it can be wrong. I just want to know about the methods to prove this.

Comment: Which text, page / problem number?

Comment: @T.Eskin can you think of a possible way to prove this?

Comment: Any "possible way to prove this" would begin by finding out what the question means.  We do not prove meaningless statements.

Comment: @AndreasBlass just because we can't figure out a problem in a go doesn't make it meaningless.

Comment: What makes the problem meaningless is not our inability to solve it but rather the presence of undefined symbols.  By "undefined" I mean that nothing in your question indicates what the $y$'s with subscripts are supposed to be.  I wouldn't be surprised if, somewhere else in your textbook, there is an indication that would clarify the question; I think that's the reason why Macavity asked about the text, page, and problem number.

Comment: Educated guess: $y_n$ is in fact $y^{(n)}$, that is an $n$'th derivative.

Comment: @AndreasBlass successive differentiation rule of leibnitz may work but while attempting I'm not getting any proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

This approach might work:

$\frac d{dx} \left(y^{\frac 1m}\right )+\frac d{dx} \left(y^{-\frac 1m}\right )=\frac d{dx} \left(2x\right )$

$\frac 1m \left(y^{\frac 1m -1}\right )\frac {dy}{dx}-\frac 1m \left(y^{-\frac 1m -1}\right )\frac {dy}{dx}=2$

$\left(y^{\frac 1m}-y^{-\frac 1m}\right )\frac {dy}{dx}=2my$

$\frac d{dx}\left(y^{\frac 1m}-y^{-\frac 1m}\right )\frac {dy}{dx}+\left(y^{\frac 1m}-y^{-\frac 1m}\right )\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}=2m\frac {dy}{dx}$

$\left(\frac 1m \left(y^{\frac 1m -1}\right )+\frac 1m \left(y^{-\frac 1m -1}\right )\right )\frac {dy}{dx}+\left(y^{\frac 1m}-y^{-\frac 1m}\right )\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}=2m\frac {dy}{dx}$

$\left(y^{\frac 1m} + y^{-\frac 1m} \right )\frac {dy}{dx}+my\left(y^{\frac 1m}-y^{-\frac 1m}\right )\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}=2m^2y\frac {dy}{dx}$

$\left(y^{\frac 1m} + y^{-\frac 1m} \right )\left(\frac {dy}{dx}\right)^2+my\left(y^{\frac 1m}-y^{-\frac 1m}\right )\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}\frac {dy}{dx}=2m^2y \left(\frac {dy}{dx}\right)^2$

$2x\left(\frac {dy}{dx}\right)^2+2m^2y^2\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}=2m^2y \left(\frac {dy}{dx}\right)^2$

Use these to prove thet statement true for $n=0$ then proceed by induction.